# How to cycle through data using navigation buttons?

Tags: c#, sql, textbox, tostring, sqldatareader

I've got a form that loads some values from my SQL database, and it appears to be loading the data correctly.

One thing my form is supposed to allow users to do is to navigate backwards and forwards through the list of rows.  I've Googled some methods for doing this, but the things I've tried haven't worked.

I'm still new to SQL and C#, so I'm a bit lost.  What is a good, elegant way to have my form be able to cycle through the data with a backwards and forwards navigation button?

Thanks for reading.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Data.Sql;

namespace AccountManager
{
    public partial class EditCustomer : Form
    {
        public EditCustomer()
        {
            InitializeComponent();    
        }

        private void EditCustomer_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                string conString = "Data Source=.;Initial Catalog=AccountMGR;Integrated Security=True;";
                SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(conString);

                string selectSql = "Select [Id], [AccountRef] ,[BusinessName] ,[BusinessAddress1]" +
          ",[BusinessAddress2]" +
         " ,[BusinessTown]" +
          ",[BusinessCounty]" +
          ",[BusinessPostcode]" +
          ",[BusinessCountry]" +
          ",[ContactTitle]" +
          ",[ContactFirstName]" +
          ",[ContactLastName]" +
          ",[ContactAddress1]" +
          ",[ContactAddress2]" +
          ",[ContactTown]" +
          ",[ContactCounty]" +
          ",[ContactPostCode]" +
          ",[ContactCountry]" +
          ",[ContactLandline]" +
          ",[ContactMobile]" +
          ",[ContactEmail] from Company";

                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(selectSql, con);

                try
                {
                    con.Open();

                    using (SqlDataReader read = cmd.ExecuteReader())
                    {
                        while (read.Read())
                        {
                            AccountRef.Text = (read["AccountRef"].ToString());
                            AccountName.Text = (read["BusinessName"].ToString());
                            BusinessAddress1.Text = (read["BusinessAddress1"].ToString());
                            BusinessAddress2.Text = (read["BusinessAddress2"].ToString());
                            BusinessTown.Text = (read["BusinessTown"].ToString());
                            BusinessCounty.Text = (read["BusinessCounty"].ToString());
                            BusinessPostcode.Text = (read["BusinessPostcode"].ToString());
                            BusinessCountry.Text = (read["BusinessCountry"].ToString());
                            ContactTitle.Text = (read["ContactTitle"].ToString());
                            ContactFirstName.Text = (read["ContactFirstName"].ToString());
                            ContactLastName.Text = (read["ContactLastName"].ToString());
                            ContactAddress1.Text = (read["ContactAddress1"].ToString());
                            ContactAddress2.Text = (read["ContactAddress2"].ToString());
                            ContactTown.Text = (read["ContactTown"].ToString());
                            ContactCounty.Text = (read["ContactCounty"].ToString());
                            ContactPostcode.Text = (read["ContactPostCode"].ToString());
                            ContactCountry.Text = (read["ContactCountry"].ToString());
                            ContactLandline.Text = (read["ContactLandline"].ToString());
                            ContactMobile.Text = (read["ContactMobile"].ToString());
                            ContactEmail.Text = (read["ContactEmail"].ToString());  
                        }
                    }
                }
                finally
                {
                    con.Close();
                }
            }
            finally
            {
                string conString = "Data Source=.;Initial Catalog=AccountMGR;Integrated Security=True;";
                SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(conString);

                string selectSql = "Select Balances.id, Balances.AccountRef, Balance, PreviousBalance, LastInvoiceDate, NextInvoiceDate, InvoiceCycle from Balances inner join Company on Balances.Id = Company.Id where Company.AccountRef = @AccountRef";

                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(selectSql, con);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@AccountRef", AccountRef.Text.Trim());

                try
                {
                    con.Open();

                    using (SqlDataReader read = cmd.ExecuteReader())
                    {
                        while (read.Read())
                        {
                            AccountRef.Text = (read["AccountRef"].ToString());
                            CustomerBalance.Text = (read["Balance"].ToString());
                            CustomerLastInvoiceDate.Text = (read["LastInvoiceDate"].ToString());
                            CustomerNextInvoiceDate.Text = (read["NextInvoiceDate"].ToString());
                            CustomerInvoiceCycle.Text = (read["InvoiceCycle"].ToString());
                        }
                    }
                }
                finally
                {
                    con.Close();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Consider using an ORM like Dapper or Entity Framework.  Indexing into a data reader by field name is error-prone and slow and a lot of work.  Then look up the `OFFSET FETCH` clauses on SQL select statements.

Comment: @Flydog57 Will check that out.

Comment: Rephrased the question, and improved the formatting on the code.  Communicating questions can be tricky; a useful technique is to separate the background of the problem being solved, from the question being posed.  This way, others will be more easily able to identify the problem.  For code, some whitespace is good, but try not to leave too much in.  Code can be long, and in order for us to help you in a timely manner, removing anything unnecessary helps others figure out things more quickly.

Comment: @AndrewGray thanks for the edit, it’s now much easier for people to understand what I’m trying to do. I did this before a few years ago but lost the code when my pc died.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure I fully understand but if you set the 'TabIndex' property of each control, you can set button or key events to cycle through each control/row.

Might look something like this..

```
    private void EditCustomer_KeyUp(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Down)
        {
            this.ProcessTabKey(true);
        }
        if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Up)
        {
            this.ProcessTabKey(false); // False Indicates backwards
        }
    }
```